# what is the wrong in this code(openAl in vc++)

Tags: visual-c++-6

how are you all?

i need your help

i have  this code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <al.h>
#include <alc.h>
#include <alut.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "openal32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "alut.lib")

/*
 * These are OpenAL "names" (or "objects"). They store and id of a buffer
 * or a source object. Generally you would expect to see the implementation
 * use values that scale up from '1', but don't count on it. The spec does
 * not make this mandatory (as it is OpenGL). The id's can easily be memory
 * pointers as well. It will depend on the implementation.
 */

// Buffers to hold sound data.
ALuint Buffer;

// Sources are points of emitting sound.
ALuint Source;


/*
 * These are 3D cartesian vector coordinates. A structure or class would be
 * a more flexible of handling these, but for the sake of simplicity we will
 * just leave it as is.
 */

// Position of the source sound.
ALfloat SourcePos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Velocity of the source sound.
ALfloat SourceVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };


// Position of the Listener.
ALfloat ListenerPos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Velocity of the Listener.
ALfloat ListenerVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Orientation of the Listener. (first 3 elements are "at", second 3 are "up")
// Also note that these should be units of '1'.
ALfloat ListenerOri[] = { 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };



/*
 * ALboolean LoadALData()
 *
 *  This function will load our sample data from the disk using the Alut
 *  utility and send the data into OpenAL as a buffer. A source is then
 *  also created to play that buffer.
 */
ALboolean LoadALData()
{
    // Variables to load into.

    ALenum format;
    ALsizei size;
    ALvoid* data;
    ALsizei freq;
    ALboolean loop;
    // Load wav data into a buffer.

    alGenBuffers(1, &Buffer);

    if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR)
        return AL_FALSE;

    alutLoadWAVFile((ALbyte *)"C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Graduation Project\OpenAL\open AL test\wavdata\FancyPants.wav", &format, &data, &size, &freq, &loop);
    alBufferData(Buffer, format, data, size, freq);
    alutUnloadWAV(format, data, size, freq);

    // Bind the buffer with the source.

    alGenSources(1, &Source);

    if(alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR)
        return AL_FALSE;

    alSourcei (Source, AL_BUFFER,   Buffer   );
    alSourcef (Source, AL_PITCH,    1.0      );
    alSourcef (Source, AL_GAIN,     1.0      );
    alSourcefv(Source, AL_POSITION, SourcePos);
    alSourcefv(Source, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVel);
    alSourcei (Source, AL_LOOPING,  loop     );

    // Do another error check and return.

    if(alGetError() == AL_NO_ERROR)
        return AL_TRUE;

    return AL_FALSE;
}



/*
 * void SetListenerValues()
 *
 *  We already defined certain values for the Listener, but we need
 *  to tell OpenAL to use that data. This function does just that.
 */
void SetListenerValues()
{
    alListenerfv(AL_POSITION,    ListenerPos);
    alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY,    ListenerVel);
    alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION, ListenerOri);
}



/*
 * void KillALData()
 *
 *  We have allocated memory for our buffers and sources which needs
 *  to be returned to the system. This function frees that memory.
 */
void KillALData()
{
    alDeleteBuffers(1, &Buffer);
    alDeleteSources(1, &Source);
    alutExit();
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("MindCode's OpenAL Lesson 1: Single Static Source\n\n");
    printf("Controls:\n");
    printf("p) Play\n");
    printf("s) Stop\n");
    printf("h) Hold (pause)\n");
    printf("q) Quit\n\n");

    // Initialize OpenAL and clear the error bit.

    alutInit(NULL, 0);
    alGetError();

    // Load the wav data.

    if(LoadALData() == AL_FALSE)
    {
        printf("Error loading data.");
        return 0;
    }

    SetListenerValues();

    // Setup an exit procedure.

    atexit(KillALData);

    // Loop.

ALubyte c = ' ';

while(c != 'q')
    {
        c = getche();

        switch(c)
    {
            // Pressing 'p' will begin playing the sample.

        case 'p': alSourcePlay(Source); break;

            // Pressing 's' will stop the sample from playing.

            case 's': alSourceStop(Source); break;

            // Pressing 'h' will pause the sample.

            case 'h': alSourcePause(Source); break;
        };

    }


    return 0;
}
```

and it is run will>>but  i cant here any thing>>

also i am new in programong and wont to program  a virtual reality sound in my graduation project >>>and start to learn opeal and vc++ 
but i dont how to start and from where i must begin

and i want to ask if i need to learn about API win ?? and if i need how i can learn that>>

thank you alote

and i am sorry coz of my english

Comment: Have you looked at OpenAL samples? There are some in OpenAL11CoreSDK. Don't forget to install oalinst too since it's going to create the hook between OpenAL and your sound device if not already done.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried running this very same [sample source code](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/openal-tutorials/lesson1.php) from devmaster.net as well. Make sure to change the #includes to reflect the appropriate paths to your OpenAL header files. If you are using C++ and not C, you will need to change #include <conio.h> to be #include <iostream> and use getchar() instead of getche().

Also, I've discovered that the version of alut.h that I have declares the alutLoadWAVFile function to only accept 5 parameters, not 6. The 6th parameter in this example (the loop variable) makes for too many arguments to the function (at least in my version of OpenAL).

{Edited note: Okay, I just discovered that apparently, the Windows version of OpenAL requires the 6th boolean loop parameter, while the Mac version of OpenAL does not.}

Hope this helps.